# is there any way to write to group many functions with similar parameters?

Tags: java, android

in recent project, I have to write a lot of `functions` in same `class` with similar first few parameters like below:

```
doA(string t, int x);
doB(string t, int x, object y);
....
doN(string t, int x, object... ns);
```

Can we have a generic `function` like `doA()` function, so that any function which `extend doA` function must have 2 parameters `string t, int x`? as `doB extends doA(object y)` instead of `doB()` above?

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You cant extend a method signature. In Java `extends` is allowed for class and interface; not for method. To share common parameter among multiple methods you could changed them to instance variable.

e.g.

```
class YourClass {

   String t;
   int x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do something like that:

```
class A{
    // not accessible by child
    private void doA(int a){
        ...
    }
    // accessible by child and B can be null
    public void doA(int a, Long B){
          doA(a);
    }
 }

 class B extends A{

     @override
     public void doA(int a, Long b){
          ...
     }
 }
```

I hope I got your question right.

If you need to access A's private method you can change its accessibility with reflections.